# Pthread using only one thread when encapsulated into a class

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I don't understand why when "encapsulated" into a class, pthread use only one thread whereas it uses all the threads when using plain calls to pthread functions. There should be something wrong in the implementation.

See the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>


namespace {
  class Functor {
  public:
    Functor(const std::vector<int> &v) :
      m_v(v), m_res() {
    }

    Functor() : m_v(), m_res() {
    }

    void operator()() {
      computeImpl();
    }

    std::vector<int> getResult() const {
      return m_res;
    }

  private:
    std::vector<int> m_v;
    std::vector<int> m_res;

    void computeImpl() {
      //Long computation (remove duplicates)
      for (size_t i = 0; i < m_v.size(); i++) {
        bool duplicate = false;

        for (size_t j = 0; j < m_res.size() && !duplicate; j++) {
          if (m_v[i] == m_res[j]) {
            duplicate = true;
          }
        }

        if (!duplicate) {
          m_res.push_back(m_v[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  void * thread(void * args) {
    Functor* f = reinterpret_cast<Functor*>(args);
    (*f)();
    return 0;
  }

  double measureTimeMs() {
    struct timeval tp;
    gettimeofday(&tp,0);
    return(1000.0*tp.tv_sec + tp.tv_usec/1000.0);
  }

  class MyThread {
  public:
    MyThread(void * (*func)(void *), void *arg) : m_pid() {
      pthread_create(&m_pid, NULL, func, arg);
    }

    MyThread() : m_pid() { }

    virtual ~MyThread() {
      join();
    }

    void join() {
      pthread_join(m_pid, NULL);
    }

  private:
    pthread_t m_pid;
  };
}

int main() {
  //Pthread encapsulated into a class
  size_t nb_threads = 4;
  std::vector<MyThread> threads(nb_threads);
  std::vector<Functor> functors(nb_threads);

  std::vector<int> v(100000);
  srand(0);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
    v[i] = rand();
  }

  double t_thread = measureTimeMs();
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nb_threads; i++) {
    functors[i] = Functor(v);
    threads[i] = MyThread(thread, &functors[i]);
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < nb_threads; i++) {
    threads[i].join();
  }
  t_thread = measureTimeMs() - t_thread;
  std::cout << "Pthread encapsulated into a classs" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "t_thread=" << t_thread << " ms" << std::endl;


  //Only Pthread
  std::vector<pthread_t> pid(nb_threads);
  t_thread = measureTimeMs();
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nb_threads; i++) {
    functors[i] = Functor(v);
    pthread_create(&pid[i], NULL, thread, &functors[i]);
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < nb_threads; i++) {
    pthread_join(pid[i], NULL);
  }
  t_thread = measureTimeMs() - t_thread;
  std::cout << "Only Pthread" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "t_thread=" << t_thread << " ms" << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

> Pthread encapsulated into a classs
>
> t_thread=4056.75 ms
>
> Only Pthread
>
> t_thread=2619.55 ms

My environment: Ubuntu 16.04 and I use System Monitor to check the CPU activity. In the first case (encapsulation), only one thread is at 100% whereas it uses 4 threads at 100% in the second case.

Also, my computer has 2 cores / 4 threads.

Comment: Simplify  your code.  For one thing you don't need all this C-style casting to `(size_t)`.  Just use `size_t` variables in the first place.  Then, use a debugger, or `cout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup for your threads are introducing copies. Further, the sources of those copies are being destroyed synchronously as the threads are created (and therefore started, run, and joined before the next thread is started, etc.). And adding final salt into the wound, the join is being done twice as well.

Changing the setup:

```
std::vector<MyThread> threads;
std::vector<Functor> functors;

threads.reserve(nb_threads);
functors.reserve(nb_threads);

for (int i = 0; i < nb_threads; i++)
{
    functors.emplace_back(v);
    threads.emplace_back(thread, &functors[(size_t) i]);
}

// will fire all destructors, and consequently join.
threads.clear();
```

Note we don't fire the `join` method here. Your destructor already does that, and will be fired when the thread vector is `clear()`-ed. Further. we reserve space for the threads, and construct them in-place in the vector.

Running the above should get you the number similarity you seek.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed my issue. This part of code is from a library, how to modify the implementation to be able to use compilers without C++11 and `emplace_back`?

Comment: @Catree that is considerably more tedious (ain't C++11 and later just grand?). It would require setting up a "start" mechanism to start the threads once they're in-place in the vector rather than starting them at construction-time. We're almost 6 years past the C++11 final spec, and every reputable vendor has it now (even MS), so weigh that to determine if its even worth pursuing.

Comment: You are right about C++11 support. Will talk with the lib maintainer to consider more C++11 code. I used a vector of pointer to `MyThread` to avoid the copy problem. Is it safe to call `pthread_join` multiple times? Otherwise, maybe using a flag to avoid calling again `join()` in the destructor.

Comment: @Catree nice alternative. Fyi, joining a pthread that has already been joined invokes undefined behavior, so prolly wanna steer clear of that.